# How can I transform an adjacency matrix into an incidence matrix?

Tags: python, matrix, graph, adjacency-matrix, adjacency-list

I created an adjacency matrix from an adjacency list, but I don't know how to create the incidence matrix from this data.

My code is this:

```
import numpy

graph = {'1': [{'2':'15'}, {'4':'7'}, {'5':'10'}],
    '2': [{'3':'9'}, {'4':'11'}, {'6':'9'}],
    '3': [{'5':'12'}, {'6':'7'}],
    '4': [{'5':'8'}, {'6':'14'}],
    '5': [{'6':'8'}]}

def weighted_adjmatrix(adjlist, nodes):
    '''Returns a (weighted) adjacency matrix as a NumPy array.'''
    matrix = []
    for node in nodes:
        weights = {endnode:int(weight)
                   for w in adjlist.get(node, {})
                   for endnode, weight in w.items()}
        matrix.append([weights.get(endnode, 0) for endnode in nodes])
    matrix = numpy.array(matrix)
    return matrix + matrix.transpose()



weighted_adjmatrix(graph, nodes=list('123456'))´
```

When I run it it throws this array:

```
array([[ 0, 15,  0,  7, 10,  0],
       [15,  0,  9, 11,  0,  9],
       [ 0,  9,  0,  0, 12,  7],
       [ 7, 11,  0,  0,  8, 14],
       [10,  0, 12,  8,  0,  8],
       [ 0,  9,  7, 14,  8,  0]])
```

Comment: What's wrong with the input that you have?

Comment: Nothing, my code is fine. I just need to expand so that I also generate an incidence matrix

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding (and according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Incidence_matrix&oldid=1053190313)), the incidence matrix should have columns representing the edges and rows representing the vertices.

Now there is no explicit edge index in your input data. Let's look at a trivial graph given as vertices and edge list:

```py
import numpy

vertices = {0, 1, 2}
edges = [(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)]
assert all(l in vertices and r in vertices for l, r in edges)

incidence_matrix = numpy.zeros([max(vertices) + 1, len(edges)], dtype="int")
for i, edge in enumerate(edges):
    l, r = edge
    incidence_matrix[l][i] = 1
    incidence_matrix[r][i] = 1

print(incidence_matrix)
```

This results in the following incidence matrix:

```
[[1 1 0]
 [1 0 1]
 [0 1 1]]
```

Translated to your example (with edge indices inferred by order of the graph dict, assuming it is ordered like in Python 3.7+) this results in this:

```py
def weighted_incidence_matrix(graph, nodes):
    edges = [
        (left, right, weight)
        for left in graph
        for edge in graph[left]
        # edge is actually a dict {target: weight}
        for right, weight in edge.items()
    ]
    assert all(l in nodes and r in nodes for l, r, _ in edges)
    incidence_matrix = numpy.zeros([len(nodes), len(edges)], dtype="int")
    for i, edge in enumerate(edges):
        l, r, weight = edge
        l = nodes.index(l)
        r = nodes.index(r)
        incidence_matrix[l][i] = weight
        incidence_matrix[r][i] = weight
    return incidence_matrix

print(weighted_incidence_matrix(graph, "123456"))
```

with the output matrix

```
[[15  7 10  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [15  0  0  9 11  9  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  9  0  0 12  7  0  0  0]
 [ 0  7  0  0 11  0  0  0  8 14  0]
 [ 0  0 10  0  0  0 12  0  8  0  8]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  9  0  7  0 14  8]]
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.